# Если установлен флажок, добавить класс родителю

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня при клике на чекбокс добавляется класс ко всем родителям с классом
"section" а нужно только для родительского блока, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.section').addClass("checked");
  } else {
    $('.section').removeClass("checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="section__item">Какой-то текст</div>
  <div class="section__item">
    <label class="section__label">
    <span>Клик</span>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="form[]">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="section__item">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="section">
  <div class="section__item">Какой-то текст</div>
  <div class="section__item">
    <label class="section__label">
    <span>Клик</span>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="form[]">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="section__item">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="section">
  <div class="section__item">Какой-то текст</div>
  <div class="section__item">
    <label class="section__label">
    <span>Клик</span>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="form[]">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="section__item">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('.section').addClass("checked");
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.section').removeClass("checked");
  }
});
```

---

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.section').toggleClass("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: С п а с и б о !

Comment: @BekzodM Пожалуйста. Успехов.